# Why Elmah set 0 for code in internal errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

Recently I created an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and installed Elmah.MVC.2.1.2 from the nugget package management on it.

Every things looks OK and Elmah logs all errors but when it logs internal errors it set 0 for code. I think it should set 5xx error code for theirs, am I right or not? If I'm right, where should I configure it?

[image]

Thanks in advanced (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ELMAH only shows the status code, if the thrown exception is of type HttpException. You can either catch the exception inside the controller and re-throw it as a HttpException or write a filter converting uncaught exceptions to HttpException.